# Continuity of the popcorn function at irrationals, when $x$ is rational

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, continuity

Consider the following function:

$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
0 & \text { if } x \text { is irrational } \\
\frac{1}{d} & \text { if } x\left(=\frac{n}{d}\right) \text { is rational. }
\end{array}\right.$

Where $n,d\in \mathbb{Z}$, $d>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I am trying to prove that this function is continuous at irrational numbers. Is the following correct?

Consider an arbitrary irrational number, $a$. Consider an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Consider an arbitrary $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose first that $x$ is rational. There exists some interval, $(N,N+1), N\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $a\in (N, N+1)$. Given the result that there are only finitely many rational numbers in $(N, N+1)$ such that $f(r)\geq\epsilon$, there must exist a $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \implies f(x)<\epsilon$. But, by the definition of $f$, $f(x)<\epsilon \implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$ (since $f$ is strictly positive for all rational numbers) $\implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ (since $f$ is zero for all irrational numbers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity of Thomae's Function at Irrationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910719/continuity-of-thomaes-function-at-irrationals)

Comment: @AnneBauval No, since that questions entails a method of proof different to the one I have attempted to use, here. I want to know whether my approach is correct.

Comment: Your approach is essentially the same (and is correct).